# Probability of hitting aircraft.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Please, help me to understand how to solve this task with Bernoulli formula.

The aircraft is being fired at. In order to hit the plane, it is enough to hit either one of the N = 8 fuel tanks with two shells, or two adjacent tanks. The fuel tanks are located in the fuselage one after the other. What is the probability that the aircraft **will be hit** if a) two b) three shells hit the tank area.

So far, I wrote down when the aircraft won't get hit.
1-3-5,
1-3-6,
1-3-7,
1-3-8,
1-4-6,
1-4-7,
1-4-8,
1-5-7,
1-5-8,
2-4-6,
2-4-7,
2-4-8,

So, at the end it's N = 8^3, M(barA) = 16*3! = 96 \ \ M(A) = 512 - 96= 416 \ \ => \ \ P(A) = 416/512. **But the question is, is there the easier way to do it with Bernoulli formula?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: There seems to be some information missing.  What is the probability that shell hits a fuel tank?  Is it the same for each tank?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume each tank has the same probability of getting hit.

a) This can be divided into the cases where two tanks get hit and adjacent tanks get hit.

$$8\cdot\left(\frac 18\right)^2+2\left(\frac18\right)^2\cdot 7=0.34375$$

b) This can be found by one minus the cases where there is no adjacent/ no two more hit on the same tank.

$$1-\left(\frac18\right)^33!\left(4+{4\choose 2}2+{4\choose 3}\right)=0.765625$$

Number of cases where there is no adjacent/ no two more hit on the same tank can be found by creating

```
{} x {} _ x {} _ x {}
```

with `x` representing a tank hit, `_` representing a must-have gap between two hits, and filling the `{}` with the remaining $3$ tank slots.

- There are $4$ cases with spreading the remaining 3 tank slots to each
  of the four brackets.
- There are ${4\choose 2}2$ cases spreading the remaining 3 tank slots into a (1,2) combination.
- There are ${4\choose 3}$ cases spreading the remaining 3 tank slots individually.